# How do I efficiently create a cross-platform 1000+ entry database system?

Tags: python, database

I am making a program that needs to store an item name to an item value for 1000+ items. I was originally thinking of using a csv file, but it would have to loop over all the values to get to the desired one. I might be able to put together a complicated function to efficiently do this, but I would rather not reinvent the wheel. I don't want the user to have to download any scripts outside of the Standard Python library. I would use MYSQL, but windows does not natively support it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you even googled anything? Also, 1000 entry is not so big, you can call it actually tiny.. :)

Comment: Yes I have, but I don't know of a cross platform solution. More specifically, the best for my current situation.

Comment: What do you mean by cross platform? Windows, linux, OSX?

Comment: Yes, preferably more, but the rest don't matter too much to me.

Comment: If all you're doing is serializing k:v pairs, just `shelve` up a `dict` and call it a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, i think the easiest way is to use the built-in interface for the database engine SQLite.

From its [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), here's a little explanation about it:

> SQLite is a C library that provides a lightweight disk-based database
> that doesn’t require a separate server process and allows accessing
> the database using a nonstandard variant of the SQL query language.
> Some applications can use SQLite for internal data storage. It’s also
> possible to prototype an application using SQLite and then port the
> code to a larger database such as PostgreSQL or Oracle.

It's disk-based, so it's lighter and faster for small cases.

Hope it helps!